# Application.ThreadException is not called

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

My WinForms app installs Application.ThreadException event handler to process all unhandled exceptions (the handler displays a dialog box: Error occured, click here to send bug report, etc).

The problem is that my event handler doesn't get called when the application displays a modal dialog. When I show a MessageBox or my exception dialog, all exceptions are silently swallowed. Is there a way to catch them?

Below is a sample WinForms application that simulates this behavior. When this application shows a MessageBox, all exceptions thrown in the background are lost (ThreadException handler is not called):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

    var form = new MyForm();
    Application.ThreadException += (s, e) =>
    {
        form.AppendText("ThreadException event handler is called.");
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Exception);
    };

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(form);
  }
}

class MyForm : Form
{
  public MyForm()
  {
    Controls.Add(TextBox = new TextBox
    {
      Multiline = true,
      Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    });

    ThrowUnhandledException(1);
    ThrowUnhandledException(2);
    ThrowUnhandledException(3);
  }

  private async void ThrowUnhandledException(int delaySeconds)
  {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delaySeconds));
    AppendText("Throwing a NotImplementedException!");
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  private TextBox TextBox { get; set; }

  public void AppendText(string message)
  {
    TextBox.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);
  }
}
```

**EDIT. I've updated the code to make things more clear.**

When an exception is thrown, MyForm writes to the TextBox: *Throwing a NotImplementedException!*

When the ThreadException handler is called, it writes: *ThreadException event handler is called.* and then it shows a message box.

**If all exceptions were caught, my TextBox would show the following:**

```
Throwing a NotImplementedException!
ThreadException event handler is called.
Throwing a NotImplementedException!
ThreadException event handler is called.
Throwing a NotImplementedException!
ThreadException event handler is called.
```

**But it shows:**

```
Throwing a NotImplementedException!
ThreadException event handler is called.
Throwing a NotImplementedException!
Throwing a NotImplementedException!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try replacing

```
Application.ThreadException += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Exception);
```

with

```
Application.ThreadException += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Exception);
```

and you will see that the event handler does get called every time.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Event handler is **not called when MessageBox is shown**. Try writing to console and then displaying a message box in your handler.

Comment: @yallie I see your point. Try serializing async calls with `await`s as in `await ThrowUnhandledException(`

Comment: This part of the code is just a simulation. In my real application events occur asynchronously (i.e. async server call throws an exception).

Comment: @yallie I suggest working around it. Display a non-modal form, or just make a note of every exception in a queue and then process them one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I've already tried that. Exception form is not the only modal form in my application, I just cannot force all forms to be non-modal. And I can't intercept every unhandled exception because ThreadException handler is not called.

Comment: Also, I tried installing the first-chance exception handler on the current AppDomain. But that gives me all exceptions, even those that will be handled in user code while I only need the unhandled ones.

Comment: @yallie Not all modal forms are problematic, just that one in exception handler.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for this observation. I haven't noticed that other dialog boxes don't block the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your program but it seems to work fine for me. The `ThrowUnhandledException` gets called 3 times. All three messages get appended to the TextBox.

I tried adding a MessageBox:

```
ThrowUnhandledException(1);
ThrowUnhandledException(2);
ThrowUnhandledException(3);

MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```

but that works as expected too. I get the message box but if I put a breakpoint on the exception handler it gets called three times. And when I close the message box, I can see all three messages in the MyForm window.

Comment: That's right, all three messages get appended to the TextBox. 
**But these messages are appended BEFORE the exception is thrown.** 
How many message boxes were shown?

Comment: Please try the updated code sample. Hope it will show the problem more clearly.